# How to merge different images into one with numpy - Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have 4 different objects with a numpy array (image), how could I merge them into another numpy 3d array (2d and 3 elements in every position) so that I have just one image containing those 4 different image.

For example, lets say I have Img1, Img2, Img3 and Img4, which are independent images and are currently stored in a 2D array like this:

```
Img1, Img2
Img3, Img4
```

So what I want is to access to the 2D array where these Img are and then create one single image with them in that order. I have this which works for this example so you can figure out what I need, but I need something generic and efficient, for example to have it a while instead of in 2 nested for:

```
a = np.hstack((images[0][0], images[0][1]))
b = np.hstack((images[1][0], images[1][1]))
c = np.vstack((a,b))
misc.imshow(c)
```

This code creates one single image from those I mentioned but I need it to be able to handle any subimage to create the main image, plus need it to be efficient (like having just a while instead of 2 for) :/

Can someone give me a hand please?

Thanks and regards.

Comment: So in essence this is what an rgb image array is. Is that what you are trying to achieve. Not sure if it could be visualized otherwise.

Comment: Can you provide more context and sample code? It sounds like you just want a tensor which is representable as an N-Way numpy array.

Comment: Yeah Grr, they're arrays containing RGB, lets say I have Object1, Object2, Object3 an Object4. Then I wanna get the first two in the first row and last two in a second row. SO they're merged in a new RGB nump array

Comment: I've edited the post with more info.

Comment: I don't understand how what you want is different than the code you show already. You mention something like `while` and `for` loops, but there are no loops in the code you've shown, so I have no idea what you're referring to. If you're doing lots of image manipulation, and you want the code you be simpler, you might have a better time using a more image-centered library like Pillow rather than low-level numpy stuff.

Comment: That example is for an 2D array of 4 images, I need it to work for any amount of images.